# Cant find clear example for futter_share_me packgae

Tags: flutter, dart

I cant find example for flutter_share_me package  , becuse I dont understand what is url and msg in package , can you please give me an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would your use case be?

Maybe it would be better to use the "share" plugin.

https://pub.dev/packages/share

It is very simple, but if you have to use flutter_share_me I suggest taking a look at the plugin's gitHub repository, the only example I found was that!

https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_share_me/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Maybe if you need to understand more about the plugin it is interesting to install it and take it deeper!

Hope this helps!

Note: I believe the URL, and MSG are just what will be shared, not necessarily leading somewhere!

Comment: Thank you foe replaying , share plugin is general share(mean after pressing share bottom will open alot of apps to share but share_with_me will open twitter or facebook or instagram). but share with me in msg and url cant use it becuse gives me error